# Need help Serializing System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand to XML?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

Trying to write a list of oracle commands to XML but keep getting this error.  This is driving me crazy.  Thanks in advance.

"There was an error reflecting type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand'."

```
Friend Sub WriteDataToFile(ByVal Commands As List(Of System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand))
    Try

        Dim PathName As String = OffloaderDataPath() & "Commands " & Now.ToLocalTime.Ticks.ToString & ".XML"


        Dim writer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand))
        Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(PathName)
        writer.Serialize(file, Commands)
        file.Close()

        If BackgroundWorkerDatabase.DataBaseInsertsIsCancelled = True Then
            BackgroundWorkerDatabase.Run()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToLog("CollectorFacility.WriteDAtaToFile: " & ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: What part of the exception do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a memento or something that would extract the state from the OracleCommand, things like CommandText, CommandType, Timeout, and so on.

It may not make sense to serialize the Parameters property.